# how to create or update a column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataframe `x`:

```
item   S  sale
A1     1   5
A1     2   10
A2     1   3
A2     2   7
A2     3   8
```

and I want the result in exactly this format

```
item   S  sale  cumsum
A1     1   5      5
A1     2   10    15 
A2     1   3      3
A2     2   7      10
A2     3   8      18
```

I have created a dictionary with item and as key value and using for loop

```
x_dict=df.groupby(['item']).apply(lambda g: g.S.values).to_dict()

for i , j in x_dict.iteritems():
```

but I am unable to access value its giving error:

> (Unexpected EOF file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['cumsum'] =  df.groupby('item')['sale'].cumsum()
print df
  item  S  sale  cumsum
0   A1  1     5       5
1   A1  2    10      15
2   A2  1     3       3
3   A2  2     7      10
4   A2  3     8      18
```